# Substitute characters in string

Tags: java, string

I am trying to create a string which substitutes all spaces for a * but I can't figure out exactly how to do that. Can anyone help?

```
String phrase = new String ("This is a String test.");
```

Comment: What language do you use? In C# it would be `var result = phrase.Replace(' ', '*');`

Answer (score 11):

Assuming it's Java, you can use the [String.replace](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29) method:

```
phrase = phrase.replace(' ', '*');
```

Answer (score 4):

Mystring = Mystring.Replace(' ', '*');

Comment: How do you know it's C#? there is no such String constructor that takes another string.

Comment: @Bala R The 2 are so close who cares?? Replace or replace. Big deal. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
String phrase = new String ("This is a String test."); 

/*Replace the Spaces with the *, */

String finalString = phrase.Replace(' ', '*');    

System.out.println(finalString);
```

Comment: I believe that "Replace" doesn't starts with capital letter. At least, Eclipse said to me :P. Apart from that, works like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do not create String with **new** operator. In Java, String is a special class. So

```
    String phrase = "This is a String test.";
```

is enough. Creating String with **new** operator will create string twice.